# find a file and copy it to another directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory called `main`. This directory is located in the root I mean the path to this directory is like this: `/HOME/main`

Inside this directory there is a folder called `f1` and inside it another folder called subf1, so the path is like this: `/HOME/main/f1/subf1`

I want to check **if there is a file in `subf1` with a name containing a special string** and copy this file to the `main` directory. I use this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*string*" -exec cp {} ../main \;
```

It's incomplete and I don't know how to check **if condition** here, but even when I execute this command in `/HOME/main/f1/subf1` path, it doesn't work. what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use it like this:

```
find /HOME/main/f1/subf1 -iname "*string*" -exec cp {} /HOME/main/ \;
```

Comment: Since I'm writing a long script, isn't it possible not to change the directory and use another command than "cd"?